# Error when I do first migration in .NET Core 8

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a solution that contains three project.

1. `EmployeeManagement.Database` -- class library where the `DbContext` is defined
2. `EmployeeManagement.Entities` -- class library that contains all my entities
3. `EmployeeManagement.WebAPI` -- Web API project

I am trying to create a `DbContext` that inherits from `IdentityDbContext`, but I got this error when I try to use `dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration` from my `EmployeeManagement.WebAPI` project.

ERROR:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[EmployeeManagement.Entities.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.TimeProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderExtensions+PostConfigureSecurityStampValidatorOptions'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[EmployeeManagement.Entities.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.TimeProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderExtensions+PostConfigureSecurityStampValidatorOptions'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IPostConfigureOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidatorOptions] Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderExtensions+PostConfigureSecurityStampValidatorOptions': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.TimeProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderExtensions+PostConfigureSecurityStampValidatorOptions'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.DataProtectorTokenProvider`1[EmployeeManagement.Entities.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.DataProtectorTokenProvider`1[EmployeeManagement.Entities.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.IDataProtectionProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.DataProtectorTokenProvider`1[EmployeeManagement.Entities.ApplicationUser]'.)
>
> No DbContext was found in assembly 'EmployeeManagement.WebAPI'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

My `DbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
  
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

`ApplicationUser` class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

`program.cs`:

```
using EmployeeManagement.Database;
using EmployeeManagement.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.MapIdentityApi<ApplicationUser>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=EmployeeManagementDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=PPPP;Password=PPPPPP;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, I had a solution with following folder structure.

```
soln
  --> Data
  --> Service
  --> Model
```

To run migration in Data folder whereas startup class is set to Service, please follow below Package Manager Console Commands to run one-by-one.

**Add Migration Command**

```
Add-Migration {Migration_Name} -Project Data -StartupProject Service
```

*NOTE: Replace {Migration_Name} with new Migration file Name*

**Update Database Command**

```
Update-Database -Project Data -StartupProject Service
```

Once all required packages installed and set your WebAPI project as startup project, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are running the migration from the wrong project.

You can define the project with the parameter `--startup-project`

`dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration --startup-project ../EmployeeManagement.Database`

If you use visual studio Package Manager Console to run the command, you should also select the correct default project.

Comment: EmployeeManagement.Database it is a class library that contains only my dbContext class. when I run this I got: Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project. If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure add a reference to your migrations project(`EmployeeManagement.Database`) from the startup project(`EmployeeManagement.WebAPI`).

```
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\EmployeeManagement.Database\EmployeeManagement.Database.csproj" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

Then run the command:

```
PM> dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project EmployeeManagement.Database --startup-project EmployeeManagement.WebAPI
```

Reference:

[Using a Separate Migrations Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)